# Tooltip text read from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip

In my php website I have a table with 100 rows, and for each cell I need seperate tooltips. So I have a text file which have the set of texts for each cell.

I want to read the text from the external file and place it as the tooltip for each cells.

Can you guide me in solving this issue?

```
<div class="divClass1" id="idClass1" > 
    <span  title="My tip"  class="context-menu-1">673</span>
    <span  title="My tip"  class="context-menu-2">674</span>
    <span  title="My tip"  class="context-menu-3">675</span>
    <span  title="My tip"  class="context-menu-4">676</span>
    <span  title="My tip"  class="context-menu-5">677</span>
    <span  title="My tip"  class="context-menu-6">678</span>
    <span  title="My tip"  class="context-menu-7">679</span>
</div>
```

This is one of the div and like this 100 others are there.
My external file is named **dependecy.txt** and it have data like

```
1   tooltip for cell1
2   tooltip for cell2
3   tooltip for cell3
4   tooltip for cell4
5   tooltip for cell5
6   tooltip for cell6
```

etc

I want to replace title for class named: "**context-menu-1**" with the text "**tooltip for cell1**".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a json file with key and value pair,where cell id will be key and tooltip text will be value.
for example,

```
{
   "toolTipInfo":{"cell1" : "tool tip text 1"},
                 {"cell2" : "tool tip text 2"},
                  . . .
                 {"cell100" : "tool tip text 100"}
}
```

now you can parse this json file in javascript and find  values with respective keys.